# About Find() method

Tags: c#

I'm testing out some coding in C# and having a little bit of problem. I have created a Node class:

```
public class Node
    {
        public string NodeName { get; set; }
        public LinkedList<Node> _item;
        public LinkedList<Node> Child { get { return _item; } set { _item = value; } }
        public Node()
        {
            _item = new LinkedList<Node>();
        }
        public void AddChild(Node a, Node b)
        { 
             a.Child.AddLast(b);
        }
     }
```

And in main method I've create a list to store the Nodes

```
Node A = new Node { NodeName = "A" };
Node B = new Node { NodeName = "B" };
Node C = new Node { NodeName = "C" };
List<Node> nodes = new List<Node>();
nodes.Add(A), nodes.Add(B), nodes.Add(C);
```

I've tried to do this and print out the children of A

```
A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"), nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "B"));
A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"). nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "C"));
foreach(var child in nodes
.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"))
{
      Console.Write(child.NodeName);
}
```

But the result got me nothing.

I want to pass the item in list as the parameter of the function so what should I do?

Comment: Is `node` a typo in `node.Find`?

Comment: it should be `nodes.Find`. And it will return the `A`. to be able to access the children of it you should access its childern.

Comment: Sorry, it's just my mistake pasting the code in here. The origin one is still nodes.Find()

Comment: OT: surely your `_item` and `Child` members should have plural names, not singular. Surely you would add a child to something named `Children`, not something named `Child`.

Comment: I'm not sure that your code really makes sense. Every `Node` contains its own `LinkedList`, so you are really creating a network of interrelated lists, not a single list. That `AddChild` method doesn't really make sense either, given that it never actually refers to the current `Node` object. Why would you need to pass in the parent node rather than treating the node you call the method on as the parent?

Answer (score 0):

Let's concentrate on the last snippet and actually examine what it does:

```cs
A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"), nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "B"));
A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"). nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "C"));
foreach(var child in nodes
.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A"))
{
      Console.Write(child.NodeName);
}
```

The first line adds node B as a chaild of node A, then the second line adds node C as a child of node A. So far, so good. Now, what does the last line do? If finds all nodes in the list with the name "A" and displays their `NodeName`. is that what you actually want? Obviously not. If you want to display the names of the child nodes then you need to actually get those child nodes, which you've made no attempt to do.

Firstly, let's rewrite your class so it makes a bit more sense:

```cs
public class Node
{
    public string NodeName { get; set; }

    public LinkedList<Node> Children { get; }

    public Node()
    {
        Children = new LinkedList<Node>();
    }

    public void AddChild(Node child)
    {
        Children.AddLast(child);
    }
}
```

The property name has been changed from `Child` to `Children`, as all lists should have plural names. The setter has also been removed, because there's no reason to be able to replace the existing list with a new one from the outside. The `AddChild` method has also been made more sensible by adding the child to the current node, rather than ignoring the current node completely and using a parent passed in. It's still not ideal but it makes more sense than before so it's good enough for now.

Now we can clean up the code you have a bit to use the nodes and actually get the children that we want to display. The whole point of the `Children` list is to store the children, so it should be obvious that we need to use that. Nowhere did you use your `Child` property in your existing code.

```cs
var A = new Node { NodeName = "A" };
var B = new Node { NodeName = "B" };
var C = new Node { NodeName = "C" };

var nodes = new List<Node> { A, B, C };

A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "B"));
A.AddChild(nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "C"));

foreach (var child in nodes.Find(x => x.NodeName == "A").Children)
{
    Console.WriteLine(child.NodeName);
}
```

This adds B and C as children of A, then enumerates A's list of children. Note sure why you're using `Find` all over the place, given that you have each node assigned to a variable, but that's by the by.

Comment: What should I do to get the child of A?

Comment: @NguyênNguyễn, you should wait until I provide all the information. I wrote "More to follow" for a reason.

Comment: @NguyênNguyễn, there, done.